# GeoNetwork installation/configuration

Tags: installation, geonetwork

Does anybody know how to install GeoNetwork in a port other than the deafault(8080), because, in my machine this port is already occupied and i don't want to remove the program running on this port because of its complexity.

Comment: Is running on tomcat a possibility for you?

Comment: It is windows installer version of Geonetwork running on jetty server

Comment: Perhaps this manual works for you https://www.seegrid.csiro.au/wiki/Infosrvices/GeoNetworkSetup#Install_web_server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out \jetty\etc\jetty.xml file, modify this line:

```
            <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
```

change 8080 into port number you want, save the file and restart geonetwork.